# How to Make a Fixed Div go Across the Screen

Tags: html, css

**Hi** there, I am looking for a way to make my div box with all of my social media widgets at the top of the website to go across the whole screen, float to the right, and stay at the very top of the page. Here is the site's link: [totempole.ca](http://thetotempole.ca/)

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>The Totem Pole News</title>
<meta name="description" content=" A totem pole themed news website posting articles on music, movies, video games, mobile applications, and news.">
<link href="thecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="socialmediaplugins">
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.thetotempole.ca" data-width="The pixel width of the plugin" data-height="The pixel height of the plugin" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
<g:plusone></g:plusone>
</div>
<div id="container">
<div id="banner">
</div>
<div id="navbar">
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div id="navbar2">
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<!-- This is the end of the container div -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
    #container {
        width: 960px;
        height:150px;
        position:relative;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    #socialmediaplugins {
        float:right;
        position:fixed;
        width:100%
        height:100px;
        background-color:#999;
        margin:0;
    }

    #banner {
        background-image:url(images/totempolebanner.gif);
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        width:960px;
        height:150px;
    }

    #navbar {
        float:left;
        position:absolute;
        top: 170px;

    }

    #navbar2 {
        float:right;
        position: relative;
        top:170px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to do so with -webkit-transition (with CSS3) [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: @CristobalDeLeon Ahmm, what? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "left:0", "top:0", and for the very top-positionning: "top:0".

```
#socialmediaplugins {
    text-align: right;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: The code works to make the div go to the very top of the page and go all the way across :) although, the social media plug ins do not float to the right.

Comment: Answer updated! BTW: Float is something else, you mean you want to align your content!